# Can you add properties to the <> empty element in React?

Tags: reactjs

can someone explain the `<>` in React, it is a div or what, I see that is different basically on design, can I add a property to it, for example, if you are iterating it and want to add the required index, how can I do that?

Something like this?:

```
todos.map((t, i), => <key={i}>{t.name}</>)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

they are
[Fragments:](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)
you can use `<React.Fragment key={item.id}>` instead of `<>`

```
function Glossary(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.items.map(item => (
        // Without the `key`, React will fire a key warning
        <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <dt>{item.term}</dt>
          <dd>{item.description}</dd>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The doc describes it quite well:

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

The Idea of the fragment element is not to receive any properties. If you want to apply properties you are better of with a `div`, `span`, or some other native component.

In your case, I would go with a div and pass the key directly to it. ->

```
todos.map((todo) => <div key={todo.name}>{todo.name}</div>)
```

FYI: have accessibility in mind when choosing the right component.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, but I fixed that with Fragments :)

Comment: Fragments most certainly can have a key property. It's stated explicitly in the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#fragment).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `React.Fragment`

> Tip: it's not a good idea to use `index` as key.

```
todos.map((item, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    <p>{item.title}</p>
  </React.Fragment>
));
```